# How read multiple .csv files from the same directory using dask?

Tags: python, csv, dask

I have been trying to read multiple .csv files in the same folder but I get the error in the image what am I doing wrong?

[Reading csv error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtthC.png)

Comment: Do not post errors or code as screenshots.

Comment: Nor as links! You should include the full details of your question right here.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps:

```
dask_nyc = dd.DataFrame()
for file in [file for file in os.listdir('.') if file.endswith('.csv')]:
    dask_nyc.append(dd.read_csv(file))
```